# How use Prolog from Java?

Tags: java, prolog

In the context of a Java/Eclipse application I would like to use Prolog for a particular task. What are the available solutions and tools to do that, and associated pro and cons ?

I can launch an external Prolog interpreter generating the result in a file ?
I can use a full Prolog Java Library (Prolog interpreter implemented in java) ?
I can use a java library dedicated to the communication with an external Prolog interpreter ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Manu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would give [GNU Prolog for Java](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/) a try. From the website:

> GNU Prolog for Java is an implementation of ISO Prolog as a Java library

Comment: Thanks for the link. This library falls in the ull Prolog Java Library (Prolog interpreter implemented in java), isn't it ?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using **tuProlog** [Official Site](http://alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/), [Code Repository](http://code.google.com/p/tuprolog/) on Android. They have a great embedded Prolog in the form on 1 Jar File. They are responsive too!

Answer (score 4):

A quick google returns a [list of options](http://www.declarativa.com/interprolog/systems.htm) (alas not updated in 5 years).

As for pros/cons - as I see it
*Native engine with bindings* would be the worse option when it comes to distribution and integration, but may be faster than the native Java engines (but I would want proof first).
*Java engine with API* would lead to some awkwardness at integration points, but should be easy to distribute.
*Prolog to bytecode compiler* should handle integration between the two languages nicely, and would mean that you are not shipping prolog scripts with the binary (may be a disadvantage). Big disadvantage with this - none still seem to be a live.
*Prolog-alike language to bytecode compiler*, same as above, but some still seem to be floating about, also would require knowledge of a new language.
*Java rules engine* - I'd see this as the neatest solution. Rather than use two languages code the rules in a Java-y way, but it depends on how complicated the rules are to express in that way.

A second thing to consider is - is the project still being updated. From my quick google, few are. [Prova](http://www.prova.ws/) and [Mandarax](http://code.google.com/p/mandarax/) are two exceptions from the latter options.

Answer (score 4):

When looking at multi-threaded Prolog systems, there are different
additional considerations. One desiderata is to have a separation
between threads and logic engines. This was expressed here:
http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/ALP/2011/03/concurrent-programming-constructs-and-first-class-logic-engines/

There are some Prolog systems that realize this separation. Jekejeke
Prolog is also among these systems. There is a report (*) that shows
how this separation can be put to use. In the various scenarios
we see that the "thread" is provided by a system external to the
logic engine:

- Terminal Deployment: Thread is the Java main thread.
- Standalone Deployment: Thread is the AWT/Swing thread.
- Applet Deployment: Thread is some browser thread.
- Servlet Deployment: Thread comes from web server pool.
- Client Deployment: Thread is the AWT/Swing thread.

Best Regards

http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/15_stdy/08_deploy/package.html

Answer (score 3):

You may also have a look at JPL 
http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/Java.html

Answer (score 2):

There is [Projog](https://github.com/s-webber/projog) which is a Prolog written in Java, but also provides a Prolog REPL:

> Projog provides an implementation of the Prolog programming language
> for the Java platform. /.../
>
> Projog can be used as a stand-alone console application or embedded in
> your Java applications as a Maven dependency.

```
projog.consultFile(new File("src/main/resources/test.pl"));

QueryStatement s1 = projog.createStatement("test(X,Y).");
s1.setTerm("X", new Atom("d"));
QueryResult r2 = s1.executeQuery();
while (r2.next()) {
   System.out.println("Y = " + r2.getTerm("Y"));
}
```

or implementing predicates in Java:

```
public class SingleResultPredicateExample extends AbstractSingleResultPredicate {
   @Override
   public boolean evaluate(Term term1, Term term2) {
      Atom upperCaseTerm1 = new Atom(getAtomName(term1).toUpperCase());
      return term2.unify(upperCaseTerm1);
   }
}
```

or:

```
private static class RetryablePredicate implements Predicate {
   private final String[] split;
   private final Term target;
   private int idx;

   RetryablePredicate(String[] split, Term target) {
      this.split = split;
      this.target = target;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean evaluate() {
      while (idx < split.length) {
         target.backtrack();
         String next = split[idx++];
         if (target.unify(new Atom(next))) {
            return true;
         }
      }

      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean couldReevaluationSucceed() {
      return idx < split.length;
   }
}
```