# How to use prolog in java?

Tags: java, prolog

Please, someone help me with an example. I would like to create a simple Prolog program, that adds two numbers together, and the Java program writes it to the console! So the Prolog is adding, and the a Java program is writing the result. I can write the adding in prolog, but I don't know how to invoke the prolog program in java. =( Please, someone, who can create this little example, write it here! Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How use Prolog from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303931/how-use-prolog-from-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I have found to use Prolog from Java is to use tuProlog which is a Prolog implementation in Java. http://www.alice.unibo.it/xwiki/bin/view/Tuprolog/  It is actively developed.

Unfortunately, tuProlog's performance is not as good as some much faster native Prologs (e.g. Yap,etc), so if speed is a concern, this might not work out for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the the [GNU Prolog for Java](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/).  Running an existing prolog file appears straight-forward described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/manual/Setup.html#Setup).  I haven't tried myself, but would be interested to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [X-Prolog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xprolog.xp) which is pretty evolved and quite fast.

Answer (score 1):

also there is [open source JProl library](https://github.com/raydac/jprol) which can be use for Prolog learning