# Assert facts from java to prolog

Tags: java, prolog, swi-prolog, jpl

I'm using SWI-Prolog with the JPL library.
I have a program written in Java that produces strings like these:

```
fact(1,2)
fact(2,3)
fact(1,3)
```

Then, there is a prolog file that needs this facts in the head of file.
I do not want neither insert the code in the head of file, nor use a text file, but only java.
Is there a solution for this?

Comment: easy way: call assert(fact(1,2)) on JPL interface

Comment: I've take a look a this post:
http://osdir.com/ml/lang.swi-prolog.general/2006-09/msg00070.html
Is this the solution?
If yes, I can't understand why the keyword assert is a string.
I have to use the java keyword assert, or as a simpley string to communicate with prolog?

Comment: you have several choices. The simpler is Query(string q), that issues, well, a Query of text q to SWI-Prolog engine (like you entering on console). Then q = "assert(fact(1,2))" should do.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you need to write Strings into a Prolog file from Java?

Java can write into many files types including .txt, .word, and html.  You can attempt to write to a Prolog file by using the extension name.

*FileWriter exampleFileWriter = new FileWriter("exampleProlog.pl");*

Just write the Strings, then close the file.  There are many safer and better ways to writing to files in Java.  Just look at this:

[Fastest way to write to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576222/fastest-way-to-write-to-file)

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

EDIT:  This might be of help:

[How use Prolog from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303931/how-use-prolog-from-java)

Comment: No no I wrote that I do not want this.
I want to use Java to communicate the facts to the prolong. without writing to the head of file.